# Using Integer as a key with HashMap in Java

Tags: java, collections

Recently I was looking for good implementation of `hashCode()` method in Java API and looked through `Integer` source code. Didn't expect that, but the `hashCode()` just returns the backed `int` value.

```
public final class Integer ... {
private final int value;
...
    public int hashCode() {
        return Integer.hashCode(value);
    }
    public static int hashCode(int value) {
        return value;
    }
```

It's really strange as there are a lot of papers and pages as well as packages dedicated to this question - how to design good hash function to distribute values.

Finally I ended up with this conclusion:

`Integer` is the worst data type candidate for a key when used with `HashMap`, as all consecutive keys will be places in one bin/bucked. Like in the sample above.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = HashMap<>();

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    map.put(Integer.valueOf(i), "string" + i);
}
```

There are two questions, for which I didn't find answers while googled:

1. Am I right with my conclusion regarding `Integer` data type?
2. In case it's true, why `Integer's hashCode()` method don't implemented in some tricky way when power operation, prime numbers, binary shifting are used?

Comment: Yes your conclusion is right

Comment: " all consecutive keys will be places in one bin" — no, not true at all. You seem to have some misunderstanding about how hash bucketing works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Integer is the worst data type candidate for a key when used with HashMap, as all consecutive keys will be places in one bin

No, that statement is wrong.

In fact, the implementation of `Integer`'s `hashCode()` is the best possible implementation. It maps each `Integer` value to a unique `hashCode` value, which reduces the chance of different keys being mapped into the same bucket.

Sometimes a simple implementation is the best.

From the Javadoc of `hashCode()` in the `Object` class:

> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. **However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables**.

`Integer` is one of the few classes that actually guarantees that unequal objects will have different `hashCode()`.

Comment: thx for the answer. I finally get this peace of code `if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)` from putVal()

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @Eran's answer, Java's `HashMap` also has a protection against "bad hash functions" (which `Integer.hashCode()` isn't, but still).

```
/**
 * Computes key.hashCode() and spreads (XORs) higher bits of hash
 * to lower.  Because the table uses power-of-two masking, sets of
 * hashes that vary only in bits above the current mask will
 * always collide. (Among known examples are sets of Float keys
 * holding consecutive whole numbers in small tables.)  So we
 * apply a transform that spreads the impact of higher bits
 * downward. There is a tradeoff between speed, utility, and
 * quality of bit-spreading. Because many common sets of hashes
 * are already reasonably distributed (so don't benefit from
 * spreading), and because we use trees to handle large sets of
 * collisions in bins, we just XOR some shifted bits in the
 * cheapest possible way to reduce systematic lossage, as well as
 * to incorporate impact of the highest bits that would otherwise
 * never be used in index calculations because of table bounds.
 */
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

So your "simple hash" of an integer will actually be a bit different when working with HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>   return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>   comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>   consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>   of the same application.

--> `Integer#hashCode` fulfills this.

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must
>   produce the same integer result.

--> `Integer#hashCode` fulfills this too.

> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method
>   on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>   However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>   integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>   hash tables.

--> `Integer#hashCode` fulfills this to the maximum extent, i.e. two unequal `Integer`s will *never* have the same hash code.