# Are Integers reasonable keys for Java HashMaps?

Tags: java, hashmap

The `hashCode()` of an `Integer` returns the value of the `Integer` itself.
In my application I have many `int`s / `Integers` between let's say 1 and 100, and some values which can go up to > 1000000 (1e6).

Can I use those `Integers` as resonable keys of a Java(8) HashMap, or are all "small" values gathered in the same bin (as they would be if all bins have equal range, let's say span 2^31/N hash values)?

**EDIT**
From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50273134/2055010, HashMap spreads the `hashCode()` for a key by
`return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);`, which should be fine.

Comment: HashMap calculates it's own hash based on Key hash like `(h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16)`

Comment: The interesting part is this one : `tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]`. It only takes the lowest bits. So **consecutive numbers are in different buckets**.

Comment: That part that you raised (`(h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16)`) is a consequence of the fact that we only take the lowest bits. They added that xor in the hash computation to force the highest bits to also be taken into account (but that's only for integers >= 65536)